# java client to subscribe to cometd channels

Tags: http, subscription, cometd, bayeux

Our application that will act as a client needs to subscribe to an external system that uses cometd to deliver unsolicited notifications to clients. Is there a way to achieve this without cometd libraries (via apache HttpClient for instance)? Java version mismatch is the problem - we use 1.6, but cometd require 1.7 or higher.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

CometD 2.x, albeit not under development anymore, supports back to JDK 5.

The underlying protocol ([Bayeux](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_bayeux)) is the same, so I expect a CometD 2.x client to work against a CometD 3.x server.

The alternative is for you to reimplement the Bayeux protocol from scratch, which is not that difficult but it does require a bit of work.