# CometD - how estabilish long-polling connection

Tags: http, long-polling, cometd, bayeux

Just to make sure I do this correctly. I am coding a Bayeux client to cooperate with external CometD server (via long-polling).  My client sends requests in the following order: handshake, connect, subscribe, connect. The latter connect is stalled until a message is available. When a message comes, server response. Everything works. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: What language is this client ? CometD already supports JavaScript and Java.

Comment: Java client. CometD in fact supports java and comes with client libraries, which are unfortunately java 6.

Comment: CometD's Java client is Java 7. You don't need to rewrite one, just use CometD's.

Comment: My bad. Our codebase is unfortunately java 6.

Comment: CometD 2.x is JDK 5 compliant. You want to use that rather than rewriting your own Bayeux client.

Comment: It does not really answer my question as the decision to implement our own client was already made. Besides, you also suggested that that writing a bayeux client from scratch is an alternative - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182217/java-client-to-subscribe-to-cometd-channels. Do you know if my approach described in the initial question is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the client should follow the `advice` sent by the server in the `/meta/handshake` and `/meta/connect` messages.

Subscription messages should be held by the client until a successful `/meta/handshake` reply.

Sending requests in a specific order is not exactly precise, since you would want to use at least two connections.

Therefore the `/meta/handshake` request goes first; after a successful `/meta/handshake` reply, `/meta/subscribe` and `/meta/connect` can go in parallel on two connections.

Whether the first `/meta/connect` reply is held or not is then irrelevant: your client will have a mechanism to handle `/meta/connect` messages and influence the server about holding or not the `/meta/connect` reply.

In [CometD](https://cometd.org), the first `/meta/connect` is sent with `advice: { timeout: 0 }` because the client wants to know if the server is still alive after the handshake (otherwise the first connect may be "lost" and the client could think that it is connected fine with the server when it's not). It also serves to notify client applications on the `/meta/connect` channel a first time quickly after the handshake.